# Override переопределение объекта в строку

Tags: java

Прошу объяснить, что означает переопределенная последняя запись из кода String toString():

```
public class GetMenuItemsCount {
    public String ID;
    public Object tag;

    public GetMenuItemsCount(String stringPart, Object tagPart) {
        ID = stringPart;
        tag = tagPart;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return tag.toString();
    }
}
```

Что означает метод Override понятно.

Comment: @iksuy Да, но здесь ведь это бессмысленно, т.к. класс ни от кого не наследуется и, вследствие чего, ничего переопределять не может (думаю, что именно в этом сам вопрос и заключается: "Зачем здесь такая аннотация, если он бессмысленна").

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, любой класс является наследником класса `Object`, который содержит метод `toString`, он тут как раз и переопределяется.

Comment: @iksuy Вот-вот, вы даете ответ, которого нет в той ссылке (по крайней мере в явном виде не упоминается), именно это и хотел узнать автор, наверное.

Comment: Я знаю, что значит Override. Я не пойму, что переписывает String tostring()

Comment: @IvanVovk Ну, теперь второй комментарий от _iksuy_ должен был разъяснить этот момент. Мне кажется, что стоит подредактировать вопрос, чтобы с акцентировать на этом внимание, и _iksuy_ оформить комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: То есть получается что объект, который и так может быть быть переведен в стринг, переопределяется новым методом перевода в строку. А зачем?

Comment: чтобы при вызове `GetMenuItemsCount.ToString()` получить значение `tag`, а не ошибку ибо непонятно что получить

Comment: Во! Теперь ясно - благодарю!

Comment: @IvanVovk Получается, что метод, унаследованный от `Object`, перевел бы в строку весь данный класс (в частности 2 его поля: `tag` и `ID`), а при таком объявлении при попытке перевести в строку класс получится, что приведется к строке лишь одно его поле (`tag`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вынес все в ответ:

Любой класс является наследником класса `Object`, который содержит метод `toString`, он тут как раз и переопределяется.

Метод `toString` в классе `Object` выглядит так:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Как видно, он всего лишь выводит имя класса и хэшкод объекта.
Чтобы для объекта `GetMenuItemsCount` этот метод возвращал более осмысленный результат, в данном коде он переопределен таким образом.